# [A]Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportHierarchy cannot be cast to [B]Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportHierarchy

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I am building an asp.net C# application which uses buttons to retrieve and display RDLC reports within a View. The reports load without issue on localhost but when placed on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 64-bit and served through IIS version 8.5 the error:

**[A]Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportHierarchy cannot be cast to [B]Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportHierarchy. Type A originates from 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms\12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll'. Type B originates from 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll'.**

Is given when the report loads. This is preventing the embedded jpg image from loading in the report.

I am using Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0 with no reference to version 11 in the web.config, .csproj or in the default.aspx.
I have trolled msdn.microsoft.com, stackoverflow, google and youtube... to no avail.

What could be causing this error and is there a fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

Check your GAC on your deployment machine (or other locations in the path). There may be another version of the dll hiding on the server. In fact, rereading your error, I see the path to the GAC right there in the error, so that *is* what's happening.

I recommend setting "specific version" to true in your project where you reference the dll to ensure that the same version is used on your local and remote machines

Comment: I uninstalled all versions except version 12 of the report viewer but I am now getting the error "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: How do I go about 'setting "specific version"'?

Comment: When you add the reference in your Visual Studio project, you can set the properties of the referenced assembly. One of those properties is "specific version". You can bring up properties by right-clicking on the reference and choosing properties.

Comment: However, your error is now saying "can't find version 11", so *something* is still referencing that older version. It's possible that one of the *other* references in your project in turn is referencing this older version. You'd have to find out if that is the case and either update that reference to a version that uses 12, or step back down to 11 globally, or *possibly* use a binding redirect in your web.config (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx )

Comment: Searched the entire solution for version 11 references but found none. Tried specific version option along with redirecting and both gave the same error. Then I tried stepping back to 11 globally and got the error "..type (Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer) is not compatible with the type of control (Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)". Any other suggestions?

Comment: You may not be directly referencing version 11, but one of your references may *itself* be referencing version 11. Though if this is the case, I don't know why it ran fine locally... At any rate, it's pretty clear it *wants* version 11. Did you restart your server after you uninstalled that reporting stuff? You might try that as well. Just because.